# backup ms-sql для больших баз

Tags: sql-server

Как бэкапить большие базы (файлы) в сети в хранилище?

Возможно ли как-то для командной строки написать скрипт `script.cmd`, чтобы потом его запустить в шедулере? И заодно использовать `zip`?

Answer (score 1):

У *MS SQL* есть свой собственный механизм резервного копирования. Он позволяет создавать резервные копии  (в том числе, автоматически по заданному сценарию) и сохранять их в том каталоге (хранилище), который требуется. Также этот механизм использует достаточно эффективный алгоритм сжатия.

Работа этого механизма достаточно подробно изложена в документации ([здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187048%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) и [здесь](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187510%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)) и неоднократно описывалась в соответствующих статьях (например, [здесь](http://snakeproject.ru/rubric/article.php?art=tsql_restore_backup_server) и [здесь](http://munserat.blogspot.com.tr/2013/12/ms-sql-2012.html)).

С этим механизмом можно работать как визуально (*SQL Server Management Studio*) так и из консоли (командная строка (один из возможных вариантов можно посмотреть [здесь](http://manaeff.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=915)) и *PowerShell*)